# Can’t get ‘comment’ value from camForm

Tags: angularjs, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to get ‘refusalComment’ from my form (when i write some value into it ) but i can’t make this operation every time i deploy project i got this error:

> ReferenceError: variableValue is not defined
>   at Array.eval (eval at (camunda-tasklist-ui.js?bust=7.8.0:5), :27:84)

here is my code example:

```
<form role=“form”>

var selectedDocuments=$scope.selectedDocuments=[];
var variableManager=camForm.variableManager;
var json=$scope.json={
id:1,
cardNumber:“12345678”,
organizationNameGE:“ptp”,
organizationNameEN:“psp”
};
$scope.selectedDocuments.push($scope.json);

   camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {

    // declare a 'json' variable 'customer'
    camForm.variableManager.createVariable({
      name: 'selectedDocuments',
      type: 'String',
      value: $scope.selectedDocuments
    });
  });

var comments = $scope.comments=[];
comments.length =$scope.selectedDocuments.length ;

  camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
    // value has been fetched, bind to $scope.user
    $scope.refusalComment = $( '#refusalComment', camForm.formElement).textContent(variableValue);
    console.log( $scope.refusalComment+"see comment");
    $scope.selectedDocuments=EnrichValue(variableManager.variable('selectedDocuments').value,$scope.refusalComment);
  });
 camForm.on('submit', function(evt) {
    // set value in variable manager so that it can be sent to backend


    variableManager.variableValue('selectedDocuments', $scope.selectedDocuments);

  });


function EnrichValue(data,comment){
for(var  i=0;i<Object.keys(json).length;i++){
json[i].comment=comment;
comments[i]=comment;
}

return json;
}
```

what should i change to make to get rid of this error?

Comment: MIxing jQuery and AngularJS like that is asking for grief.

Comment: Read [Camunda Forms Manual - AngularJS Integration](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/api-references/embedded-forms/#integrating-the-forms-sdk-angularjs-integration)